# FHIR: .Net Sample code for using extension & "Other" Resource

Tags: hl7-fhir

Google search didn't help. Appreciate if you can share a sample codes for how to use extensions & "Other" resource using .Net Hl7.fhir.api and spark server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at many examples of preparing & sending resources in the FHIR testsuite called [Sprinkler](https://github.com/furore-fhir/sprinkler). This is not specifically about `Other`, but there's really no difference between managing extension on `Patient` or on `Other`. To see how to put extension on *any* resource, look at the `ExtensionManagement()` unit test [here](https://github.com/ewoutkramer/fhir-net-api/blob/develop/src/Hl7.Fhir.Model.Tests/ModelTests.cs), which shows how to use extensions with the .NET API.